# Soma em TextView

Tags: java, android

Tenho um Json que retorna os valores de positivo e negativo, e que setam o texto nos meus `TextView`. Esse é o calculo que eu tento fazer, mas que retorna um erro de `invalid double`:

```
public double num1,num2,resultado;

saldo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saldouser);
negativo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vendaliv);
positivo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compraliv);
date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datatrans);

num1 = Double.parseDouble(positivo.getText().toString());
num2 = Double.parseDouble(negativo.getText().toString());
resultado = num1-num2;
System.out.println(resultado);
saldo.setText(resultado);
```

O erro é:

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Comment: Teria como você deixar o erro completo na pergunta? É melhor para quem for responder, entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Fiz a edição , inseri o erro ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das duas uma:

1) Você usa no texto um valor como `12,9` ou `10,0`com virgula, como usamos no Brasil. Mas o Double usa . como é usado nos EUA, logo ele nao consegue interpretar que `12,9` é `12.9` e explode.

2) Voce tenta dar parse em um String vazio, o que é invalido tb pois ele nao converte automatico pra 0.

Sugestao, use um bloco try catch pra tratar essa exception e/ou uma funcao pra converter sua virgula pra ponto se for esse o problema.

Comment: Provavelmente é a String vazia mesmo..

Comment: @Thiago pelo seu erro é a String vazia, se resolveu o seu problema aceite a resposta ;)